# I have found an “error” in my authenticator - extension on my Desktop. I do not know how to solve this

Tags: authentication, security, authorization, google-2fa

I can't open my (NC)wallet. All Google Authenticator Codes get refused when trying to log in.
I tried with the "entrance" of the wallet on desktop; and filled in the codes from my mobile.
I can't get the extension to work on my desktop.
Both were set to detect time automatically.[error in authenticator-extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dnvyv.jpg)
[details of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppqTf.jpg)

I already called in help from NCWallet, by means of their service "Atlassian".[cases in helpcentre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrcNI.jpg)